# how to simplify Jquery UI order of events

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am writing a calendar timeline view, when the user drags the job to a new time a dialog appears, then AJAX reloads the php content, and finally re-initializes the draggable elements so the jobs can be dragged again.

My question is likely due to not understating all the different ways to call functions, so

my question is: can this solution below be reduced to less calls?

I want to make sure I'm avoiding "double" calls  to reduce the code and use the "hierarchy"/ built in properties properly.

> Drag{
>   ----   Dialog{
>   -------      success{ AJAX{ reload-function{ initialize }  }//end AJAX  ---- } //end success
>   -------      cancel { AJAX{ reload-function{ initialize }  }//end AJAX   ---- } //end cancel
>   ---   }
>   }

Below is the current pieced together solution, it IS WORKING:

```
$("#dialog-mjob").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    resizable: true,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Modify": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "get-event.php",
                data: $('#mod-event-form').serialize(),
                success: function (data) { }
            });
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "get-event.php",
                data: $('#mod-event-form').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#cal-inner').remove();
                    $('#cal').load('timeline-inner.php', function () {
                        $(".draggable").draggable({
                            //revert: true, 
                            revert: "invalid",
                            //helper: "clone",
                            cursor: "hand",
                            grid: [44, 0],
                            axis: "x",
                            handle: "span",
                            cursor: "move",
                            stop: function (ev, ui) {
                                changePrompt($(this).attr('id'));
                            }
                        });
                    });

                }
            }); // end ajax
        } // end cancel button
    } // end buttons
}); // end dialog
```

Comment: That is a *mess* of awful indentation. If you want strangers to help you fix your code, why wouldn't you at least make it easy for them to read?

Comment: Sorry Meager, let me see what I can do, I just posted...

Comment: ok.. it cleaned up a bit.. so any thoughts on the order of the functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can replace every anonymous function

```
    variable: function() {...}
```

by a named one and then hand over it's identifier instead.

```
    variable: myFunc
...
function myFunc() {...}
```

This can help you with easing the growing nesting of code and would also allow you to reuse identical/similar functions.

```
$("#dialog-mjob").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    resizable: true,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Modify": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "get-event.php",
                data: $('#mod-event-form').serialize(),
                success: myAjaxFunction // <-- CHANGED!
            });
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "get-event.php",
                data: $('#mod-event-form').serialize(),
                success:  myAjaxFunction // <-- CHANGED!
            }); // end ajax
        } // end cancel button
    } // end buttons
}); // end dialog

// the new named function
function myAjaxFunction (data) {
    $('#cal-inner').remove();
    $('#cal').load('timeline-inner.php', function () {
        $(".draggable").draggable({
            //revert: true, 
            revert: "invalid",
            //helper: "clone",
            cursor: "hand",
            grid: [44, 0],
            axis: "x",
            handle: "span",
            cursor: "move",
            stop: function (ev, ui) {
            changePrompt($(this).attr('id'));
        }
    });
}
```

This could be done even further:

```
$("#dialog-mjob").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    resizable: true,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Modify": doModify, // <-- CHANGED!
        Cancel: doCancel    // <-- CHANGED!
    } // end buttons
}); // end dialog

function doModify() {       // <-- NEW!
    $(this).dialog("close");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get-event.php",
        data: $('#mod-event-form').serialize(),
        success: myAjaxFunction
    });
}

function doCancel() {       // <-- NEW!
    $(this).dialog("close");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get-event.php",
        data: $('#mod-event-form').serialize(),
        success:  myAjaxFunction
    }); // end ajax
}

function myAjaxFunction (data) {   // <-- NEW!
    $('#cal-inner').remove();
    $('#cal').load('timeline-inner.php', function () {
        $(".draggable").draggable({
            //revert: true, 
            revert: "invalid",
            //helper: "clone",
            cursor: "hand",
            grid: [44, 0],
            axis: "x",
            handle: "span",
            cursor: "move",
            stop: function (ev, ui) {
            changePrompt($(this).attr('id'));
        }
    });
}
```

As for the double calls I am not really sure what you mean but if you are afraid that a button is submitted twice you could set a higher scoped variable to indicate that a button was already pressed.

Comment: This a great suggestion, just what I was looking for because you addressed the "growing nested functions" , I wasn't sure what to ask but you saw where I was headed. As for doubles, again you address this because of "nests" (using code over and over, was afraid of duplication) Thank you so much.

Comment: I would totally vote up if I had the ability, maybe someone will be kind enough to do so since you not only provided and answer but 2 levels of better syntax. Thanks again!